# How to get the results of 2 rows into one

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that will only ever produce 2 rows. Each row contains one question and its matching answer. What I want to do is to have a single row with 4 columns. How can this be done? I can concat the values into a string but I'd rather not do this.

Can someone provide me with an example? This is what I'm after:

```
Q1              A1            Q2                 A2 
Some question   Some answer   Another question   Another answer
```

---

This is my query

```
SELECT question, answer FROM
user_question AS uq
Join question AS q ON q.question_id = uq.question_id
```

Comment: Muzz, how are Q1 and Q2 connected? What is userId? You need to supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you just need to query the same table twice. You should use the AS keyword so you can be sure which version of the table is being used in the SELECT and WHERE portions:

```
SELECT a.question as q1,
       a.answer as a1,
       b.question as q2,
       b.answer as a2
FROM   user_question as a,
       user_question as b
WHERE  a.question_id = 1001
AND    b.question_id = 1002;
```

Comment: Where would my `question` table be joined?

Comment: BicycleDude, I'm not able to get this to work. Also, I'll need to use the userID for the WHERE clause, not the question_id.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `UNION`?

like this:

```
SELECT iQuestion, iAnswer
FROM
    (SELECT Q1 as iQuestion, -- change to orig column name
            A1 as iAnswer,   -- change to orig column name
            questionID
    FROM    user_question INNER JOIN question
                ON user_question.question_id = question.question_id
    UNION
    SELECT  Q2 as iQuestion, -- change to orig column name
            A2 as iAnswer,   -- change to orig column name
            questionID
    FROM    user_question INNER JOIN question
                ON user_question.question_id = question.question_id) as iResult
WHERE   iResult = 'QUESTIONID HERE'
```

**PS: Please post the `SCHEMA` of your table so that we would know the exact column names and the field you will be using in `WHERE` condition.**